# Rails URL for index action includes weird wording for ActiveRecord_Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I've published a sizable update to my heroku staging site and besides some saving issues (which I'll post in a separate question), I've noticed some weird things happening to my index url.

Projects are nested under users like such:
**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources :projects do
    get "cancel", :on => :member
    post "cancel" => 'projects#cancel_save', :on => :member
    get "rate_supplier", :on => :member
    post "rate_supplier" => 'projects#rate_suppliers', :on => :member
  end
end
```

Originally when I viewed a users projects it displayed correctly as

`/users/2/projects`

But now for some reason the url looks as follows:

`users/2/projects.%23<Project::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fe577ab9820>`

I'm not sure why the rest of that stuff is in the url?? And can't find anything online. Help!

**UPDATE**

The models looks as follows:
project.rb

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :projects
belongs_to :budget
belongs_to :industry
belongs_to :project_source
belongs_to :project_status
belongs_to :project_type, class_name: 'Project_type'
has_and_belongs_to_many :features, join_table: :projects_features
has_and_belongs_to_many :addons, join_table: :projects_addons

has_one :project_close_reason
accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_close_reason

has_one :supplier_rating
accepts_nested_attributes_for :supplier_rating

scope :open, -> {
    where("project_status_id <=?", 8)
}

scope :closed, -> {
    where("project_status_id >?", 8)
}

scope :cancelled, -> {
    where("project_status_id =?", 10)
}

scope :completed, -> {
    where("project_status_id =?", 9)
}   

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

validates :password, :presence => true,
                 :on => :create,
                 :format => {:with => /\A.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\@\#\$\%\^\&\+\=]).*\Z/ }
validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

has_many :projects, inverse_of: :user
has_many :businesses, inverse_of: :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects

def full_name 
    "#{last_name}, #{first_name}"
end


end
```

And here is the link:

```
<li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'projects' %>">
    <%= link_to user_projects_path(current_user, @projects) do %>
        <i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Projects
    <% end %>
</li>
```

And here is the index action in the projects controller

```
def index
  @title = "Your Projects"
  @projects = current_user.projects
end
```

Comment: How are you using the URL prefix?

Comment: show us how the model associations are defined and how the link is defined

Comment: I've tried it both on a localhost and on a heroku staging site - same result for both. So for local host, the full url (including prefix) is `http://localhost:3000/users/2/projects.%23%3CProject::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f7f721ebb28%3E`.

Comment: Ok, will update question with models and links now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `link_to user_projects_path(current_user, @projects)`

I'm figuring you're trying to render the index of projects for a single user.

You don't need to pass `@projects` in this case. You can simply remove the second argument.

The route you're trying to hit is `/users/:user_id/projects`.

Since this route only has one parameter (`:user_id`), you only need to pass one argument to `link_to`.

To link to individual project show pages, you can do this:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= link_to user_project_path(current_user, @projects) %>
<% end %>
```

Note the difference between `user_projects_path`, which takes only one argument, and `user_project_path`, which takes two.

Comment: Magic! Thanks thats perfect, and makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Stephen yeah, this is an example of Rails magic. The url helper methods (`user_project_path`) are generated when you call `resources`.